# How to fix "Spawn EACCES" error from linter-flake8

Tags: linux, atom-editor, linux-mint, flake8

linter-flake8 creates the error "spawn `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/flake8` EACCES" in Atom on OS Linux Mint.

I changed the default Executable Path to `/usr/local/bin/flake8` as some people suggested before, but the directory lacks of "flake8" ("Make sure `/usr/local/bin/flake8` is installed and on your PATH").

I tried install 'linter-flake8' through terminal and via Atom, but result is the same.

I search on my computer for the file named "flake8" and found the following path `/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/flake8`, but result is the "Spawn EACCES".

The error that I have now:

```
[Linter] Error running Flake8 Error: spawn /usr/share/bash-completion/completions/flake8 EACCES
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:229)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:406)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you are installing it through Atom make sure that flake8 is executable by user atom. Also make sure that in configuration you are referring directly to flake8 and not just working directory.

Spawn EACCES is permission-related error so you can also fix this by [chown/chmod](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-use-chmod-and-chown-command/) commands over executable flake8 file and/or its working directory.

For example:

`sudo chmod -R a+rwx APPNAME/file`

Keep in mind that it also makes APPNAME writable to everyone, which on servers is a huge security risk.

Comment: What do you mean by "flake8 is executable by user atom"?
I am not sure if it is the right flake8, I have two of files on my PC with that name, but one of them is empty, so I can suggest this isn't the right one.
Moreover, I discovered that the file flake8 had root permissions, so I changed them to my user ones, but still I have the same error.

Answer (score -1):

that file is unrelated to flake8 (it's tab completion provided by some other package) - you don't currently have flake8 installed

you'll need to install it using `pip install flake8` or some similar command